# Check value in every month

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

I have this table

```
declare @tbl table(dDay datetime, data int)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-14 11:03:18',20)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-12-17 09:22:03',50)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-14 10:38:06',35)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-12-14 10:41:24',10)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-14 10:44:53',13)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-17 09:22:03',11)
insert into @tbl values ('2013-03-22 17:46:02',111)
```

:

```
+----------------------------+------+
|            dDay            | data |
+----------------------------+------+
| March, 22 2013 17:46:02    |  111 |
| November, 14 2014 10:38:06 |   35 |
| November, 14 2014 10:44:53 |   13 |
| November, 14 2014 11:03:18 |   20 |
| November, 17 2014 09:22:03 |   11 |
| December, 14 2014 10:41:24 |   10 |
| December, 17 2014 09:22:03 |   50 |
+----------------------------+------+
```

How can I check in every months if data is greater than X ?

For example I want to sum these values but if in any month it's greater than 50 next month it must be summed from scratch.

Here data in November is `(20 + 35 + 13 + 11)` and its `79`. `79 > 50`. So in December there must not be `(20 + 35 + 13 + 11) + 50 + 10`. Instead there must be `50 + 10` (60 in that case).And that for all month

Looking for output :

```
+-------+-------------------+
| month |        sum        |
+-------+-------------------+
|     3 | 111               |
|    11 | 20 + 35 + 13 + 11 |
|    12 | 50 + 10           |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: what output do you want - one row, three rows ( a plane ) ?

Comment: @amdixon plane is really god idea. month - data will good output

Comment: yes one for each month @amdixon

Comment: @amdixon yes it is thanks

Comment: do you also reset the sum when next month is not adjacent ? also are you using mysql or tsql - please adjust the tags

Comment: I'm using t-sql. yyes i need to reset sum for next month after it will more than 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plan**

> - aggregate sum of data grouping by month as `sum_data_v`
> - take `row_number` over `sum_data_v`
> - join above to itself on sequential row_numbers
> - calculate partitioning logic by summing over resetting indicator if previous month sum_data > 50
> - sum sum_data over above calculated partition

**setup**

```
create view sum_data_v
as
select month(dDay) as mnth, sum(data) as sum_data
from [table]
group by month(dDay)
;
```

**sample input**

```
+----------------------------+------+
|            dDay            | data |
+----------------------------+------+
| March, 22 2013 17:46:02    |  111 |
| May, 22 2013 17:46:02      |   22 |
| June, 22 2013 17:46:02     |   13 |
| July, 22 2013 17:46:02     |   17 |
| November, 14 2014 10:38:06 |   35 |
| November, 14 2014 10:44:53 |   13 |
| November, 14 2014 11:03:18 |   20 |
| November, 17 2014 09:22:03 |   11 |
| December, 14 2014 10:41:24 |   10 |
| December, 17 2014 09:22:03 |   50 |
+----------------------------+------+
```

---

**query**

```
select [month],
SUM(sum_data) OVER(partition by 
                   prt
                   ORDER BY [month] 
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS csum
from
(
select 
[left].mnth as [month],
[left].sum_data,
sum(case when ([right].mnth is not null and [right].sum_data > 50)
         then 1
         else 0
         end) 
over(order by [left].mnth
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prt
from
(
select mnth, sum_data,
row_number() over(order by mnth) as rn
from sum_data_v
) [left]
left join
(
select mnth, sum_data,
row_number() over(order by mnth) as rn
from sum_data_v
) [right]
on [left].rn = [right].rn + 1
) [parts]
order by [month]
;
```

**output**

```
+-------+------+
| month | csum |
+-------+------+
|     3 |  111 |
|     5 |   22 |
|     6 |   35 |
|     7 |   52 |
|    11 |  131 |
|    12 |   60 |
+-------+------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac0e1/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
declare @tbl table(dDay datetime, data int)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-14 11:03:18',20)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-12-17 09:22:03',50)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-14 10:38:06',35)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-12-14 10:41:24',10)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-14 10:44:53',13)
insert into @tbl values ('2014-11-17 09:22:03',11)
insert into @tbl values ('2013-03-22 17:46:02',40)
insert into @tbl values ('2013-02-22 17:46:02',20)
insert into @tbl values ('2013-01-22 17:46:02',10)



;with cte_table
as
(
select 
row_number() over (order by datepart(mm,dday)) as rn,
datepart(mm,dday) as dmonth, sum(data) data ,case when sum(data) > 50 then 1 else 0 end as flag

from @tbl group by datepart(mm,dday) 

)


select 
c1.dmonth,
c1.data,
case when c1.data > 50 then c1.data else ((isnull(c1.data,0)+isnull(c2.data,0))) end as totaldata
from 
cte_table c1 left outer join cte_table c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn+1
```